# angularfire2 timeout and cancel for saving data

Tags: angular, promise, timeout, angularfire2

I want to set timeout & cancel for firebase database saving data.
Current code is as follows

```js
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
export class XXX{

 constructor(private af_db: AngularFireDatabase){} 

 const items = this.af_db.list('/path');
 const promise = items.push(data);
 promise.then(()=>{

 }).catch((err)=>{

 })
```

In this code, when user is offline, it keep on waiting for network connection, and after the connection established, saving data is executed.
I want to set two features for it

**cancel:**
 when user click "close" button, undergoing saving process is stopped.

**timeout:**
 when more than 3 seconds passed after starting to process save, the saving process finished and show "try again".

Answer (score 2):

*Cancel*. You can't cancel promises, as soon as operation started you have no control over it.

*Timeout*. If you you want to use timeout for this specific operation then I believe it is not possible. Even if you show timeout message to a user after 3 seconds the operation itself is in progress and will succeed or fail later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification.
I found out that saving data does not work well in the unstable internet connection, I need to find a way to notify the situation to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple API (with Express) into Cloud Functions. Then set a timeout for HTTP and play with Observable.retry, maybe something like:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
this.sub = this.http.post(urlToYourCloudFunction, data, {timeout: 1000, headers:{authorization: this.authToken}})
    .retry(3)
    .timeout(4000);
```

To cancel:

```
if (this.sub) { this.sub.unsubscribe(); }
```

Isn't 100% proof. It's still possible you lose connection during the time it takes Cloud Functions to send you a response back. And if it's a push, not an update, you might end up with duplicates. You can avoid that by creating the key on client side thus making it an "upsert".